# How can I get my output string array by passing reference into a function in C?

Tags: c

When I am trying to get my output using the code in bellow, It's always stopped. But why and how can I solve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void nameView(char* []);

int n, i, j;

int main(){

   char name[10][10];

    printf("Enter case: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(i=0; i<n; ++i){
        printf("Enter Name: ");
        scanf("%s", name[i]);
    }

    nameView(&name);


    return 0;
 }

  void nameView(char *b[]){

   for(i=0; i<n; ++i){

        printf("\n%s", *b[i]);
    }
 }
```

Programmed has stoped but when I replaced

```
    for(i=0; i<n; ++i){

        printf("\n%s", *b[i]);
    }
```

Insead of "nameView(&name)" in main function it's work.How can I output by passing reference in "nameView()" function

Comment: Your function prototype is different than the function declarator in definition.

Comment: How can that compile?  Surely, a function mismatch is a fatal error?

Comment: like [this](http://ideone.com/dZ78wh)

Comment: This is just write mistake here.....

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the '%s' input format specifier, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer to avoid buffer overflow.  Such overflow is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.  Suggest: `if( 1 != scanf("%9s", name[i]) ) { // handle error }`

Comment: there are only 10 rows in the `char name[10][10]` so the code should be checking the variable 'n' to assure the value is in the range 0...10 so the array `name[][]` cannot be overflowed

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: the posted code contains a 'magic' number: 10.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: regarding: `void nameView(char *b[])`  this is saying an array of pointers to char is being passed, however, there is only a single pointer being passed. suggest: `void nameView(char b[][10])`   (also fix the prototype)

Comment: regarding: `nameView(&name);`  In C, a reference to an array name degrades to the first address of the array, so inserting a '&' before the name is a logic error.

Comment: it is (almost always) best to limit the scope of a variable.  There for the variables: 'n', 'i', and 'j' should be moved inside the smallest scope available..   Note: the variable 'j' is not used.

Answer (score 2):

As was mentioned in the comments, your function prototype:

```
void nameView(char* []);
```

Does not match the definition:

```
void nameView(char *b){
```

Additionally, the argument you pass in (`&name` which is `char (*)[10][10],  i.e. a pointer to a 2D array) doesn't match either parameter.

You need to declare and define your function like to take a 2D array of 10x10 `chars`:

```
void nameView(char b[10][10]){
```

Or equivalently, a pointer to an array of size 10:

```
void nameView(char (*b)[10]){
```

And call it with the name of the array:

```
nameView(name);
```

Comment: Or alternatively declare as `void nameView(char b[][10]);`.

Answer (score 0):

The following proposed code:

1. implements the corrections to the problems highlighted in the comments.
2. cleanly compiles
3. performs the desired functionality
4. checks for errors
5. eliminates the (very undesirable) global variables
6. limits the scope of the variables
7. documents why each header file is included

and now the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>  // scanf(), printf(), perror()
#include <stdlib.h> // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE

#define MAX_NAMES  10
#define MAX_LENGTH 10


// prototypes
void nameView(char [][ MAX_LENGTH ], int);


int main( void )
{
    char name[ MAX_NAMES ][ MAX_LENGTH ];
    int n;

    printf("Enter case: ");
    if( 1 != scanf("%d", &n) )
    {
        perror( "scanf for number of names failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful

    EDIT:
    //if( 0 < n || n > MAX_NAMES )
    if( n < 0 || n > MAX_NAMES )
    {
        printf( "invalid entry for Name count, must be in the range 1...10\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, 'n' contains a valid value

    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        printf("Enter Name: ");
        if( 1 != scanf("%9s", name[i]) )
        {
            perror( "scanf for name failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }

    nameView(name, n);
    return 0;
} // end function: main


void nameView(char b[][ MAX_LENGTH ], int n)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        printf("\n%s", b[i]);
    }
} // end function: nameView
```

Comment: @DavidBowling,  I agree with your assessment.  My error, I'll correct it in the answer.